# Any big open fields of monsters in diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 2, my favorite place to farm was the secret cow level, because it boiled down the formula to its essence: **there are a lot of guys, kill them and take their stuff**.

But in Diablo 3, all of the areas seem to involve navigating complex environments and battling foes with special attacks that you must dodge, counter, etc.

I mean, overall that's very much a good thing; it keeps the combat fresh. But sometimes I just wanna turn off my brain and kill hordes of enemies without traversing a maze or dealing with their tactical shenanigans.

So, **have any of you found a fun grind-tastic area like the old secret cow level?**

[image: cows]

Comment: You could try playing Pied Piper in Fields of Misery (Act 1), Leoric's Hunting Grounds (Act 1), Stinging Sands (Act 2) and several other places - till you run into a vortex or waller mob.

Comment: Did you try `Whimsyshire` already?

Comment: yeah, I've tried Whimsyshire, but it seems underpopulated compared to the 'ole cow level, and the map isn't as wide open

Comment: Pretty much every single level is an open field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most open-wide zones in Diablo 3 should be the following:

- Field of Misery (Act 1)
- Southern Highlands (Act 1)
- Stingin Sands (Act 2)
- Dahlgur Oasis (Act 2)
- Desolate Sands (Act 2)
- Fields of Slaughter (Act 3)

If you want to kill many monsters at time just run around inside these zones and let them follow you. After a couple of minutes of running around you should have some fun.

Comment: Fields of Slaughter are brutal fun :)

Comment: Sounds like a plan! Thanks for the neat lil list :)

Answer (score 2):

I really like playing the opening bits of Act 3 for this... its not really an open field... but there sure are gigantic mobs to wade thru like the cow levels of old. its great fun for a monk like mine. When you have to light the signal torches, as well as raising the catapults you will see lots of great action.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only on Act II but so far the most concentrated areas that I've found so-far are the **Dahlgur Oasis** (as mentioned above) and the **Forgotten Ruins**.

I was actually surprised at how many monsters are in the **Forgotten Ruins**.  The spawning spires (not sure what they're actually called) will keep churning out monsters as long as you don't actually destroy them, and there are 4 or 5 of them scattered throughout the level.